# ParseJS/Angular display Parse Object rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, parsing

I'm using Parse.com for my backend and following the basic tutorial on the Parse documents. I've set a controller and can't display all the rows from the database table named Events. How would I fix the code to display all rows from the table?

```
.controller('sllc',['$scope',function($scope){   


var Events = Parse.Object.extend("Events");
var query = new Parse.Query(Events);

query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    console.log(results); 
    $scope.items = results.Array;  

  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking over some sample code, I was able to solve this question. I had to apply an extra function and return the values individually.

```
.controller('sllc',['$scope',function($scope){   


var Events = Parse.Object.extend("Events");
var query = new Parse.Query(Events);

query.find({
  success: function(results) {

    $scope.$apply(function() {
       $scope.items = results.map(function(obj) {  

           return { 
             objectId: obj.id, 
             author: obj.get("author").id,  
             eventname: obj.get("eventname"), 
             eventDescription: obj.get("eventDescription"), 

           };
       });
    });

  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
}])
```

Comment: When i do it this way, i get `$digest already in progress` error, any idea why? And without `$apply` i get this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365658/parsejs-angular-ionic-retrieving-relational-object-in-view-values-getting-displ